# How to update java heap size through docker file

Tags: docker, heap-memory

How to update heap size in tomcat linux container using dockerfile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Java heap size (Xms/Xmx) inside Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923531/how-to-set-java-heap-size-xms-xmx-inside-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

The docker image for tomcat using the `catalania.sh` script to start tomcat. The jvm memory options are read from environment variables.
In particular, you can `JAVA_OPTS` env variable to set the memory options for the JVM.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Thus when starting the container, you can simply start it as such

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` as shown below.

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"
```